# newbie need help in timer project

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just a newbie in coding and I would like to ask for some of your help on my little project. I'm currently trying to make an adjustable 99900 milliseconds countdown timer that is trigger by any sound (strong enough) it pick-up from an android phone's microphone and plays a SCARY_SOUND.mp3 located inside the phone after the timer reaches zero.
This project will be running on my android phone.

NEEDED HELP IN THE FOLLOWING:
 1.) 99900 milliseconds countdown timer
 2.) way to access and used an android phone's microphone
 3.) retrieve audio files in phone's memory

I really appreciate any help I can get.
Thank you everyone.

here is the code I currently have...

```
<div>
<table table;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><button class="Add10000">+</button></td>
<td><button class="Add1000">+</button></td>
<td><button class="Add100">+</button></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="tenthousand" style="font-size: 271px;">0</div></td>
<td><div id="onethousand" style="font-size: 271px;">0</div></td>
<td><div id="onehundred" style="font-size: 271px;">0</div></td>
<td><div id="tensones" style="font-size: 89.43px;">00</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button class="Subtract10000">-</button></td>
<td><button class="Subtract1000">-</button></td>
<td><button class="Subtract100">-</button></td>
<td></td>
</tr>  
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody><tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" style="padding-right:3px;" align="right">
<button id="Start" style="font-size: 48px;">Start</button>
<button id="Reset" style="font-size: 48px;">Reset</button>
<button id="Stop" style="font-size: 48px;">Sound Test</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: A couple suggestions to improve your post: just post relevant code. Include ideas on how you would accomplish your goals. Include attempts at how you accomplished them. Otherwise, this is off topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Just base on the Browser

1. counting down timer

`setTimeout` or `setInterval`

2. way to access and used an android phone's microphone

you can play a sound by `<audio/>` and JS, you can control the volume, pause, resume, etc

3. retrieve audio files in phone's memory

you can supply a `form`, and a `file` input in it, which the user can browse his phone memory and pick up the audio files.

but you can NOT get the file without user's interaction

by the way, I think you'd better learn some basic knowledge before you ask question on the internet----it's not good for you and for us to explain if you even don't know `setTimeout`